# Concerns about housing data mining

Tags: machine-learning, references, data-mining

Can anyone suggest me good papers related to housing data mining. I have googled for a while and couldn't find any recent paper. I am assuming that people have stopped doing any mining related to housing data. Isn't anyone working on it anymore?

I am thinking of applying data mining techniques to predict housing prices, clustering and kind of ranking of houses based upon several factors like spatial location, crime rate information, migration rate etc etc.

I am pretty sure it's not a fancy thing. There isn't much to do with it. But I was thinking of having something publishable.

Can anyone suggest me good datasets that has spatial information, pricing information and other demographics. I found one at http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Housing.

Are there any other ones?